Using log4j2 version 2.22.1 , How to add StringWriter as a parameter to Appenders like WriterAppender?
I am migrating from log4j 1.x to 2.x and in 1.x i am using StringWriter from java.io and paasing the parameter to WriterAppender in 1.0 but how to pass the same StringWriter as parameter with latest WriterAppender of 2.22.1 version
Log4j2.x to use StringWriter in any of the appenders like WriterAppender

Can you show how did you use WriterAppender in Log4j 1?

StringWriter  writer =  new StringWriter();                                                                           WriterAppender appender  =  new WriterAppender(writer, layout)

Log4j Core 2 uses a builder pattern to create layouts and appenders.
To add and remove an appender to the current Log4j Core configuration, you can use code like this:
LoggerContext context = LogManager.getContext(false);
//
// Log4j Core is not the only Log4j API implementation
// You should write a version of this code for at least Logback and JUL.
//
if (context instanceof org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext coreContext) {
    Configuration configuration = coreContext.getConfiguration();
    // A Layout
    PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
            .setConfiguration(configuration)
            .setPattern("%d [%t] %p %c - %m%n")
            .build();
    // An appender
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    WriterAppender appender = WriterAppender.newBuilder()
            .setConfiguration(configuration)
            .setName("MY_APPENDER")
            .setLayout(layout)
            .setTarget(writer)
            .build();
    // In order: start and add
    appender.start();
    configuration.getRootLogger()
            .addAppender(appender, null, null);
    // Use the appender
    // ...

    // In order: remove and stop
    configuration.getRootLogger()
            .removeAppender(appender.getName());
    appender.stop();
}

PS: Log4j 2 is a major release of Log4j, so the package names changed. The code above requires the following imports:
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.WriterAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext;


I tried this but  setTarget(writer) method is throwing an issue like cannot resolve method 'setTarget()' in 'Builder'

The method has been there since around 2018: cf. WriterAppender.Builder#setTarget() JavaDoc.
